# Why this expression is a characteristic function? (Infinitely Distributions)

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I'm trying to prove that the next formula is a characteristic function of an infinitely divisible distribution:

$$\phi(t)=\exp\left[i\gamma+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(e^{itx}-1-\frac{itx}{1+x^{2}}\right)\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}\nu(dx)\right],$$ where $\nu$ is a finite measure, and the integrand is equal to $-t^2/2$ at the origin.

As a suggestion to prove this is the next:

If $\mu_{n}$ has density $I_{[-n,n]}(1+x^2)$ with respect to $\nu$ then 
$$\exp\left(i\gamma t + it\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\mu_{n}(dx)+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{itx}-1-itx)\frac{1}{x^2}\mu_{n}(dx)\right)$$ is a characteristic function.

Why that expression is a characteristic function? I can't see it.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $\sigma^2 := \nu(\{0\})$ we can write

$$\phi(t) = \exp \left[ i \gamma t - \sigma^2 \frac{t^2}{2} + \int_{x \neq 0} \left( e^{itx}-1- \frac{itx}{1+x^2} \right) \frac{1+x^2}{x^2} \, \nu(dx) \right]. \tag{1}$$

Once we know that $\phi$ is a characteristic function for any $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and any finite measure $\nu$ it follows easily that the associated distribution is infinitely divisible; just note that

$$\psi(t) := \exp \left[ i \frac{\gamma}{n} t - \frac{\sigma^2}{n} \frac{t^2}{2} + \int_{x \neq 0} \left( e^{itx}-1- \frac{itx}{1+x^2} \right) \frac{1+x^2}{x^2} \, \frac{\nu(dx)}{n} \right]. $$

is a characteristic function satisfying $\phi(t) = \psi(t)^n$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

To prove that $(1)$ is indeed a characteristic function we can use an approximation argument. For fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we set

$$\mu_n := 1_{\{1/n \leq |x| \leq n\}} \frac{1+x^2}{x^2} \, \nu(dx)$$

and

$$\lambda_n := \int_{1/n \leq |x| \leq n} \frac{1+x^2}{x^2} \, \nu(dx).$$

The next step is to show that

$$\phi_n(t) := \exp \bigg[ it \underbrace{\left( \gamma - \int_{x \neq 0} \frac{x}{1+x^2} \,\mu_n(dx) \right)}_{=:\gamma_n}- \sigma^2 \frac{t^2}{2} + \int_{x \neq 0} (e^{itx}-1) \, \mu_n(dx) \bigg] \tag{2}$$

is a characteristic function. Since $\mu_n/\lambda_n$ is a probability measure, there exists a sequence of independent random variables $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that each $X_i$ has distribution $\mu_n/\lambda_n$ (recall that $n$ is fixed). Let $N$ be a Poisson distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda_n$ and let $Y \sim N(\gamma_n,\sigma^2)$ be such that $N$, $Y$ and $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are independent. A straightforward computation shows that the characteristic function of the random variable

$$Z := Y + \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$$

equals $\phi_n$ defined in $(2)$.

Now note that we can rewrite $\phi_n$ in the following way:

$$\begin{align*} \phi_n(t) &= \exp \bigg[it \gamma - \sigma^2 \frac{t^2}{2} + \int_{x \neq 0} \left( e^{itx}-1-\frac{itx}{1+x^2} \right) \mu_n(dx) \bigg] \\ &= \exp \bigg[it \gamma - \sigma^2 \frac{t^2}{2} + \int_{1/n \leq |x| \leq n} \left( e^{itx}-1-\frac{itx}{1+x^2} \right) \frac{1+x^2}{x^2} \, \nu(dx) \bigg]. \end{align*}$$

This implies $\phi_n(t) \to \phi(t)$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\phi$ is continuous at $t=0$, the pointwise convergence $\phi_n \to \phi$ entails that $\phi$ is a characteristic function.

Comment: Many thanks @saz. So complete answer. You've been a great help.

Comment: @Squird37 You are welcome. If you like the answer, you can upvote it by clicking on the up arrow next to it.

Comment: I made some edits to improve the formatting. You should also say something in case that $\lambda_n = 0$, which is possible (for example when $\nu = 0$).

Comment: You can solve this by noticing that $\lambda_n \to \nu(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})$ and thus you have to distinguish between two cases: case 1 is that $ \nu(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})= 0$ and then the integral in the definition of $\phi$ for $x \neq 0$ vanishes and it is clear that $\phi$ is a characteristic function then. Case 2 is that $ \nu(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})>0$ and then for $n$ sufficiently large $\lambda_n > 0$ and the argument you wrote works. Of course, these are just details.

Comment: @ε--δ I will take at it lateron when I have more time.

Comment: This answer is really overcomplicated if you already know that $t \mapsto \exp\left(\int_\mathbb{R} (e^{itx}-1-itx)/x^2 \mu(dx)\right)$ is a characteristic function of an infinitely divisible distribution (this is a result in Billingsley). Moreover, this question also comes from Billingsley book (exercise 28.4 in my version) and the hint in the back at the book (in my version p572) gives an idea to use this hint.

Comment: @ε--δ Then just go ahead and write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Define finite Borel measures $\mu_n, n \geq 1$ by

$$\mu_n(A) = \int_A I_{[-n,n]}(x) (1+x^2) \nu (dx), \quad A \in \mathcal{R}$$

Then, define functions $\phi_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}, n  \geq 1$ by

$$\phi_n(t) = \exp\left(i \gamma t + it \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{x}{1+x^2} \mu_n(dx) + \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{e^{itx}-1-itx}{x^2}\mu_n(dx)\right)$$
$$= \exp\left(i \gamma t + \int_{[-n,n]}\left(e^{itx}-1-\frac{itx}{1+x^2}\right)\frac{1+x^2}{x^2} \nu (dx)\right)$$

Clearly we have pointwise $\phi_n \to \phi$ and $\phi_n$ is the characteristic function of a random variable $\gamma_n + X_n$ where $$\gamma_n:= \gamma + \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{x}{1+x^2} \mu_n(dx)$$
and $X_n$ has characteristic function $$t \mapsto \exp\left(\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{e^{itx}-1-itx}{x^2}\mu_n(dx)\right)$$
See Billingsley, probability and measure, third edition, theorem 28.1, p372 for a proof that this is a characteristic function of some probability distribution.

Since $\phi$ is continuous at $0$ (invoke the dominated convergence theorem to prove this), we can conclude that $\phi$ is a characteristic function and as in the answer of @saz, it follows that it is the characteristic function of an infinitely divisible distribution.